# Sequential Integer Matrices in Python Without Packages

Tags: python, python-2.7, matrix

Just when I think I'm decent at something, I find a simple thing I cannot overcome.

I need to create a symmetrical row x column matrix given a start and block for a checksum. The entries should be in sequential order.

```
def main(start_index, block):
    num_rows, num_cols = block, block
    matrix = []

    for r in range(num_rows):
        temp = []

        for c in range(num_cols):
            temp.append(c)

        matrix.append(temp)

    return matrix
```

The output here is:
`[[0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2]]`

**What I'm trying to obtain is:**
`[[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8]]`

And not just for a 3x3 but dynamically as well.

***Note: No packages like numpy, that's not the point of this ask. Only native python.***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are appending `c` which is always a range between 0 and `num_cols`. You need to calculate `c` based on which row you are in. Something like:

```
def main(start_index, block):
    num_rows, num_cols = block, block
    matrix = []

    for r in range(num_rows):
        temp = []

        for c in range(0, num_cols):
            temp.append(start_index + c + (r * num_cols))

        matrix.append(temp)

    return matrix

main(0, 3)

>> [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8]]
```

You could also write this as a generator from `start_index` to `row * columns` that generates your rows lazily. For example:

```
def main(start_index, block):
    num_rows, num_cols = block, block

    total = num_rows * num_cols

    for i in range(start_index, total + start_index, num_cols):
        yield list(range(i, num_cols + i))

list(main(10, 4))
>> [[10, 11, 12, 13], [14, 15, 16, 17], [18, 19, 20, 21], [22, 23, 24, 25]]
```

Comment: Where did the 0th position in the 0th list entry go here?
The 0 in [0,1,2]

I manually fixed it ```start_index-1```

But I don't quite see where we missed the iteration.

Comment: @phtaedrus not sure why I was adding one. See edit.

Comment: Thanks, @Mark_Meyer. Checked. 
For the generator function, wouldn't it be considered non-python to use a while instead of for loops?

Comment: @phtaedrus, I'm not sure — I think the while loop is easier to read, but you can also do it as a for loop over a range. See edit.

Comment: I like this method a lot. Now looking into pythonic generators. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Are you overcomplicating?

```
In [1]: nrow, ncol, start = 3, 5, 7                                                       

In [2]: [[start+c+r*ncol for c in range(ncol)] for r in range(nrow)]                      
Out[2]: [[7, 8, 9, 10, 11], [12, 13, 14, 15, 16], [17, 18, 19, 20, 21]]
```

Should you prefer more descriptive names:

```
In [3]: n_rows, n_cols, n_start = 3,5,7                        

In [4]: [[n_start + col + row*n_cols for col in range(n_cols)] for row in range(n_rows)]               
Out[4]: [[7, 8, 9, 10, 11], [12, 13, 14, 15, 16], [17, 18, 19, 20, 21]]
```

Eventually, to have `itertools.count` you *absolutely* don't need to `import itertools`

```
In [10]: def count(start=0, step=1): 
    ...:     while True: 
    ...:         yield start 
    ...:         start += step 

In [11]: nr, nc, item = 3, 4, count()                                                                                                                                              

In [12]: [[next(item) for c in range(nc)] for r in range(nr)]                                                                                                                      
Out[12]: [[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11]]

In [13]: nr, nc, item = 3, 4, count(start=4, step=3)                                                                                                                               

In [14]: [[next(item) for c in range(nc)] for r in range(nr)]                                                                                                                      
Out[14]: [[4, 7, 10, 13], [16, 19, 22, 25], [28, 31, 34, 37]]
```

Comment: Hey @gboffi, I don't think so, I like the list comprehension but in this case I don't find that easily readable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [itertools.count](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.count) to create a generator for generating incrementing integers, every call to `next` will get the next integer

Then you can use this generator for filling in the values when you create your lists

```
import itertools

def get_square_matrix(size):
    counter = itertools.count(start_index)
    matrix = []
    for row in range(size):
        matrix.append([next(counter) for _ in range(size)])
    return matrix
```

Comment: Thank you! But I'm trying to use zero imports. Sorry, I 'll correct my statement but what I meant was only standard python, no imports.